# Call API every time user enters view

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Is there a React Native equivalent to Ionic's `beforeEnter()` so that I can call my API every time a user enters my friends list view.

As far as I know `componentDidMount()` only occurs once per loading of the view.

Can `fetch()` automatically call itself upon view entry - what am I missing here?

Comment: `componentWillMount` will execute every time your component is mounted into the DOM. So it will be more appropriate to put API calls inside `componentWillMount`.

Comment: API calls for data listing should be re-run every time the view opens, not once in the lifecycle of the application IMO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to put your fetch() in componentWillMount() which happens before componentDidMount()

Comment: But both of those only occur once - when the view loads

Comment: In React Native navigator, there are functions onWillFocus and onDidFocus which will be called everytime you enter the view. Check here for more details (https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/navigator.html)